# How to bind sql database row using jquery javascript $ajax in c# visual studio

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I was working on my project to bind/get the result of a Item price to view as an Unit Price in asp.net of a particular row in Sql, My table is Items with a column of ItemId, ItemName and ItemPrice with a primary key of ItemId, I used javascript jquery to perform the viewing of the Item Price. Here is my Code in Index.cshtml:

```
    '<script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Item").change(function () {
            var itemId = $("#Item").val();
            getItemUnitPrice(itemId);
            alert("No data");
        });

    });

    function getItemUnitPrice(itemId) {
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: { itemId: itemId },
            url: '/home/getItemUnitPrice',
            sucesss: function (data) {
               $("#txtUnitPrice").val(parseFloat(data).toFixed(2));
            },
            error: function () {
               alert("There is some problem to get the Unit Price.");
           }
        });
   }
</script>
<style>
    fieldset {
        border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
        margin: 0;
        xmin-width: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        postion: relative;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        padding-left: 10px !important;
    }

    legend {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        width: 35%;
        border: 1px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
</style>
<fieldset>
    <legend>
        Restaurant
    </legend>
     <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                Customer :
                @Html.DropDownList("Customer", new 
SelectList(Model.Item1, "Value", "Text"),
                htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                Payment Type :
                @Html.DropDownList("PaymentType", new 
   SelectList(Model.Item3, "Value", "Text"),
                    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" 
   })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
   <legend>Restaurant Items</legend>
   <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class=" col-md-6">
               <div class="form-group">
                Item :
                @Html.DropDownList("Item", new 
  SelectList(Model.Item2, "Value", "Text"),
   htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class=" col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                Unit Price :
                <input type="text" readonly="readonly" 
id="txtUnitPrice" value="0.00" name="UnitPrice" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                Quantity :
                <input type="text" id="txtQuantity" value="0" 
   name="Quantity" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                Discount :
                <input type="text" id="txtDiscount" value="0.00" 
  name="Discount" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                Total Amount :
                <input type="text" readonly="readonly" 
   id="txtTotalAmount" value="0.00" name="TotalAmount" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="button" style="margin-top: 20px" 
   value="Add To List" name="AddToList" id="btnAddToList" class="btn 
  btn-success" />
            </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
   <legend>Restaurant Listed Items</legend>
   <table style="width:100%">
       <thead>
          <tr>
              <th hidden>
                Item Id
            </th>
            <th>
                Item Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Unit Price
            </th>
            <th>
                Quantity
            </th>
            <th>
                Discount
            </th>
            <th>
                Total
            </th>
            <th>
                Action
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

'

Here is Home Controller:

```
   'using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using WebAppRestaurantDemoApp.Models;
    using WebAppRestaurantDemoApp.Repositories;


    namespace WebAppRestaurantDemoApp.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
        private RestaurantDBEntities objRestaurantDbEntities;
        public HomeController()
        {
            objRestaurantDbEntities = new RestaurantDBEntities();
        }
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var objCustomerRepository = new CustomerRepository();
            var objItemRepository = new ItemRepository();
            var objPaymentTypeRepository = new PaymentTypeRepository();
            var objMultipleModels = new Tuple<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, 
IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>
            (objCustomerRepository.GetAllCustomers(), objItemRepository.GetAllItems(), 
objPaymentTypeRepository.GetAllPaymentType());

            return View(objMultipleModels);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult getItemUnitPrice(int itemId)
        {
            decimal UnitPrice = objRestaurantDbEntities.Items.Single(model => 
model.ItemId == itemId).ItemPrice;
            return Json(UnitPrice, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
  
        }
    }'
```

And here is my Item Repository:
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebAppRestaurantDemoApp.Models;

```
  namespace WebAppRestaurantDemoApp.Repositories
   {
   public class ItemRepository
        {
        private RestaurantDBEntities objRestaurantDbEntities;
        public ItemRepository()
        {
        objRestaurantDbEntities = new RestaurantDBEntities();
        }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAllItems()
        {
            var objSelectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
            objSelectListItems = (from obj in objRestaurantDbEntities.Items
                                  select new SelectListItem()
                                  {
                                      Text = obj.ItemName,
                                      Value = obj.ItemId.ToString(),
                                      Selected = true
                                  }).ToList();
            return objSelectListItems;
        }


    }
    }'
```

This is my Item.cs:

```
    namespace WebAppRestaurantDemoApp.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Item
    {
       public int ItemId { get; set; }
       public string ItemName { get; set; }
       public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }
   }
  }
```

And here is the result of the run program [Result of Asp]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcfd7.png)

Comment: can you post your view

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebAppRestaurantDemoApp.ViewModel
{
    public class ItemViewModel
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }
    }
}                                                                                                                                                This is my ViewModel.cs

Comment: I mean the entire cshtml

Comment: ok wait I will edit my question

Comment: Try using annonymous object `return Json(new { price = UnitPrice }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` And in jquery `$("#txtUnitPrice").val(parseFloat(data.price).toFixed(2));`

Comment: I try it and it still no data to view, but thanks for helping